# How to extract an interface from a class with all its XMLDOC comments (class and members like properties and methods)?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, class, interface, xml-documentation

I use visual studio 2019
I have a class

```
public class User
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Create user in DB
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="user"></param>
    public void AddUser(User user)
    {
        // Create User
    }
}
```

I want to extract an interface for this class, but I want the comments of the methods in the interface too.

Comment: Very first hit on [Google](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/extract-interface?view=vs-2019); for the comments, you can use `<inheritdoc>`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ways to synchronize interface and implementation comments in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/824007/) and [Inheriting XML comments from interfaces in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3773037/) and [Comment Inheritance for C# (actually any language)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/342964/)

Comment: Try these, not sure about comments, Keyboard
Press Ctrl+R, then Ctrl+I. (Your keyboard shortcut may be different based on which profile you've selected.)
Press Ctrl+. to trigger the Quick Actions and Refactorings menu and select Extract Interface from the Preview window popup.
Mouse
Select Edit > Refactor > Extract Interface.
Right-click the name of the class, select the Quick Actions and Refactorings menu and select Extract Interface from the Preview window popup.