# Auto add ///<inheritdoc/> when implementing methods from interface

Tags: c#, visual-studio, resharper, documentation, inheritdoc

Does it exist on Visual Studio 2019 or ReSharper a way to automatically add `///<inheritdoc/>` when implementing missing members from an interface/base class?

[image]
[image]

I checked quite a bit on Google but couldn't find anything.

Comment: Have you tried this https://www.inheritdoc.io/ ?

Comment: I do not think there is one without a 3rd party also take a look here. -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/342964/comment-inheritance-for-c-sharp-actually-any-language

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski inheritdoc.io only modifies the documentation XML. From the FAQs: "Does InheritDoc modify my source code? No, InheritDoc modifies the XML documentation files associated with your assembly instead of modifying the source code"

Comment: @panoskarajohn thanks, I already found that question and I am a happy GhostDoc user. Unfortunately it does not do what I am looking for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried this option in ReSharper Options: `ReSharper | Options | Code Editing | Members Generation | Generate documentation | Add <inheritdoc /> for overridden members`? [image]