# Only show CS1591 when publicly visible type or member are not defined in interface file

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

As I described in the title. I don't think I should be reminded to write any XML doc for publicly visible type or member I already documented in its interface file.

Comment: You can just use `/// <inheritdoc />` - see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/342964/comment-inheritance-for-c-sharp-actually-any-language

Comment: If the class itself is public and you've enabled warnings/errors when undocumented, it has to be documented as it can be used without using it through the interface. You can, as @CamiloTerevinto said, specify that documentation should be inherited, but you still need to be explicit about it.

Comment: You guys answers are awesome! 1st one tell me what to do. 2nd explains the whole thing and make me consider other situations:"it can be used without using it through the interface".